# ArcGIS Server - Change Virtual Directory

Tags: arcgis-server, iis

I recently installed ArcGIS for Server 10.3.

Is there a way for me to change the virtual directory for my map services?

For example, instead of using

**http://mywebsite.com/arcgis/rest/services/**

I want to use

**http://mywebsite.com/103/**

Comment: This sounds to me as you would need to use a web adaptor for that. https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/about-the-arcgis-web-adaptor.htm

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure how that would work.  I have the web adaptor enabled to hit the GIS Server, but there is nowhere for me to specify the external URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set up a reverse proxy with your web adapter. The proxy should take care of forwarding any specified URLs to the GIS server.

Here's an ESRI article about this:

http://support.esri.com/cn/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40680

Comment: The key phrase to search for more details is Application Request Routing (ARR) in IIS.  The Esri article is pretty bare bones, so if you run into trouble, look around for ARR tutorials. For example: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing